# JavaScript innerHTML.length alternative

Tags: javascript, iframe, innerhtml

Our application loads a huge HTML file in an iframe. I know the size of the content already, so to check the download progress I am using innerHTML.length. Is there any alternative to count the number of characters loaded in an iframe.

**EDIT**

The HTML file which is loaded in iframe is large(1.5 MB+) and is generated every time compilation process is done. We would like to show the progress bar to users about the download progress and AFAIK in JavaScript there is no way to check download progress of JS (or resource) file(s), so I am using the content length of iframe to show progress bar.

Comment: I can't think of a better way.

Comment: This is the fastest way you can get the length. Maybe if you give more details about what you exactly want to achieve. We could help you more.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `innerText.length`, Not an alternate but another way to achieve this.

Comment: But innerText will exclude the html content which will result in wrong content length, right?

Comment: But you need to calculate the actual content not including the DOM because when you append the HTML to the document modern browsers automatically rectify our errors and add few tags that we have missed, then you will have the wrong numbers.

Comment: You are correct that modern browsers do rectify the errors and append/add appropriate tags but this HTML file is auto generated and chances of errors are very less and also I already know the content length on server side, so I use that in JavaScript to calculate load progress.

Comment: Plus innerText will exclude the DOM tags which means I will get different length instead of actual content length.

Comment: I thought you manually created the HTML part and receiving/sending the data. If it is auto generated then it's OK.

Comment: Yes innerText will exclude the DOM tags.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66239/discussion-between-veer-and-sachin-gorade).